# Is it a good practice to list multiple .PHONY directives in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I understand Makefile allows multiple .PHONY targets in the file:
.PHONY: target1
...
.PHONY: target2

but is it a good practice?
Why don't we just list all the phony targets in a single top-line such as:
.PHONY: target1 target2

Comment: I don't see a problem having multiple `.PHONY` directives, how could that harm?

Comment: Makefiles can have multiple multiple rules for *any* target, as long as no more than one of the rules has a recipe.  The `.PHONY` target is not special in that regard.

Comment: On the other hand, one *can*, and some makefiles *do*, use a single, combined `.PHONY` rule, as you suggest.  There are advantages and disadvantages to each style.